# Error when trying to get the URL of a page in a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Apps Script to be embedded into Google Sites to retrieve the names and URLs for child pages of the current page. When I call the getURL() function I am getting the following error:

*'TypeError: Cannot find function getURL in object WebPage.'*

My code is as follows:

```
function doGet() {

    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    var pages = SitesApp.getActivePage().getChildren();

    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(pages[i].getURL());
    }

    return app;
}
```

I am new to Google Apps Scripts so am struggling to work out what this means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `pages[i].getUrl()`

You should use the autocomplete feature in the script editor to avoid such typing errors (control space after the dot : page[i].*here type CTRL space* and you'll see all possible methods...)

Note : the general rule in javascript is to use the so called camelCase format : `getRange`, `createLabel` ... there are only a few exceptions like `setHTML` but every rule must have exceptions doesn't it ?

Comment: the simplest errors are the one we make most easily... That's why we invented technology ;-) thank you Google !!